# How to get the diff for a pull request in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

Let's say I made a pull request against a branch called `temp`.  My commits are `c1`, `c2` and `c3`.   How to get the diff for the that PR?

I can use `git diff HEAD~3 HEAD` but if I don't know I am 3 commits ahead of `temp`, how do i do that?  How to do on Jenkins?  using variables like `env.BRANCH_NAME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff temp...HEAD`

It is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base temp HEAD) HEAD`.

Suppose the history of `temp` is `A-B-C-D-E` and the one of `HEAD` is `A-B-c1-c2-c3`. `git merge-base temp HEAD` is `B` and `git diff B HEAD` is the combined diff of `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

Comment: is there a way in Jenkins to know which base branch is the PR?

Comment: @ryan Where is your repository hosted? A hosting service like Github or Gitlab provides a set of restful apis. By Gitlab's `GET /merge_requests` or Github's `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls` you can get the base branch and a lot of other details about the PR. Other hosting services should also have similar apis.

Comment: @ryan Jenkins plugin should be able to get the base branch too.